# $\operatorname{im} A = \ker A$ for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$?

Tags: matrices

Find the image and kernel of $A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ -1 & -2 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. I was told that both the image and the kernel are the lines $y = - \frac{1}{2} x$. Is this true? How do we find the image and the kernel?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of $\operatorname{im} \space$ and $\ker$?

Comment: Yes I do. I showed that both the image and kernel is all multiples of the vector $(2,-1)$, but that doesn't sound right. How can the image and the kernel be the same?

Comment: What makes you think they have to be different?

Comment: In general (for any matrix), when are they the same? I just figured they would always be different.

Comment: They don’t have to be different as your example shows. It’s even easier to see here:
$$A = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$$
That is, collapsing the horizontal axis to the origin and rotating the vertical axis onto the horizontal axis in one motion. You probably thought that they should be different, because one throws the kernel away and keeps some other part as the image. But it is not said, what is done to the other part to become the image. (The non-kernel also isn’t a linear space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let denote by $(e_1,e_2)$ the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C_1$, $C_2$ the columns of $A$. We note that $C_2=2C_1$ and $A\neq 0$ so:
$$\mathrm{Im}(A)=\mathrm{span}(C_1).$$
Moreover $C_2-2C_1=A(e_2-2e_1)=A(C_1) =0$ then:
$$\mathrm{Ker}(A)=\mathrm{span}(C_1),$$
hence you can conclude.

Finally, I find usefull to add  the following result (and I leave the proof to the OP): There is an endomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ if and only if $n$ is even.(Why?).